# I struggle to covert an IAwaitable to LuisResult (LUIS on Microsoft Bot framework)

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I´m using the class Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialog.Promptoptions that takes a ResumeAfter which is delegate and requires (IDialogContext context, IAwaitable result)

However, the delegate I want to call is a not of 
**private async Task Test (IDialogContext context, IAwaitable result)**

but rather a LUIS delegate that has the following

[LuisIntent("Test")
**private async Task Test (IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)**

It will be highly appreciated to hear some thoughts how to call the LUIS attributed method

```
    private async Task ProductChoice(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {

        PromptDialog.Choice<string>(
        context,
        ProductOverview,
        this.productOptions,
        "Which plaform are you interested in?",
        "Ooops, what you wrote is not a valid option, please try again",
        3,
        PromptStyle.PerLine);
        await context.PostAsync(context.MakeMessage());
    }        

    [LuisIntent ("Products")]
    public async Task ProductOverview(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        string product = "";
        EntityRecommendation rec;
        Activity activity = (Activity)context.MakeMessage();
        Attachment attachment;

        if (result.TryFindEntity("ProductName", out rec))
        {
            //Here you could include other rich cards
            attachment = CreateNewHeroCard(product = rec.Entity);
            activity.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            await context.PostAsync(activity);
        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Sorry, their is no product by that name");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to show more code. How you use that PromptOptions, why do you expect `LuisResult` be returned to your callback?

Comment: You may need some code refactoring and extraction what is made in your Test method to a common method used by Luis result and ResumeAfter

Comment: You won't be able to do that. But refactoring the code would be easier, use a common method.

Comment: But `PromptDialog.Choice<string>` will callback with `string` result, not `LuisResult`, so not sure how you want this to work.

Comment: The thing is I would like to use one on my LUISIntend methods (ProductOverview) not just to handle LUIS calls but also to handle some ResumeAfter calls as sometimes the method woould be invoke directly from the Bot and sometime I want the method to be part of the logic flow. Here you can see i try to invoke ProductOverview from the PromptDialog that I initiate above. Naturally this fails but how can I call my ProductOverview method from a ResumeAfter?

Answer (score 2):

First, what you are trying to do is not possible.

Then a few other things:

- You should not send a `PostAsync` after calling a `Prompt`.
- If you want to reuse some of the logic on the `LUIS` Intent method, then you need to extract that logic into a common method that both, LUIS and the ResumeAfter method of the prompt can call to. Of course, that common method shouldn't have anything related to `LuisResult`, since that won't be available in the ResumeAfter method. When the ResumeAfter method will be called; LUIS won't be called.
- If what you want is to, call `LUIS` after the prompt, then a bit more code will have to be written but it's doable
- If you just want to call your `ProductOverview` method from the ResumeAfter method, you can just do it as a standard method, however (and again), have in mind that you won't have a LuisResult there, so you will have to send a null value and handle that accordingly in your `ProductOverview` method.

Something like:

```
private async Task ProductChoice(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {

        PromptDialog.Choice<string>(
        context,
        AfterPromptChoiceMethod,
        this.productOptions,
        "Which plaform are you interested in?",
        "Ooops, what you wrote is not a valid option, please try again",
        3,
        PromptStyle.PerLine);
        await context.PostAsync(context.MakeMessage());
    }        

   private async Task AfterPromptChoiceMethod(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
       await ProductOverview(context, null);
    }
```